# Sprite Moving along UIBezierPath, How to Reverse Direction from Sprite Location

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Been working on this for quite some time now. I have the Sprite so that it moves counter clockwise along the UIBezierPath as soon as the screen is touched. I also have it so it reverses direction along the UIBezierPath, but it always goes back to the beginning of the path. I want the Sprite to reverse direction, but start at the position of the sprite. Here's all of my code, any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you have any further questions feel free to ask. :)

```
var Circle = SKSpriteNode()
var Person = SKSpriteNode()
var Path = UIBezierPath()

var gameStarted = Bool()
var clockWise = true

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    Circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
    Circle.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    Circle.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(Circle)

    Person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Person")
    Person.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 7)
    Person.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2 + 112)
    Person.zRotation = 3.14 / 2
    self.addChild(Person)


    Path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: self.frame.width / 2 - 113 , y: self.frame.height / 2 - 113, width: 226, height: 226), cornerRadius:226)


}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */


    let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 100)
    NSLog("\(self.frame.width / 2 - Person.position.x)")
     NSLog("\(self.frame.height / 2 - Person.position.y)")

    if gameStarted == false{
        gameStarted = true
        let Follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 100)
        Person.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))
        clockWise = false
    }

    else if gameStarted == true{
        if clockWise == true{
            clockWise = false
            Person.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))
        }
        else if clockWise == false{
            clockWise = true
            Person.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())
            //NSLog("\(Path.description)")
        }

    }



}
```